# Метод получающий имя метода, в котором он был вызван

Tags: java

Нужно написать метод(а), который вызывается внутри другого метода(б) и, например, выводит в консоль имя того метода, в котором был вызван(б). Какой лучший способ реализовать это?

Comment: а из каких способов вы выбираете?

Comment: пока не из каких) хочу узнать как в принципе реализовать нечто подобное

Comment: @Klanar1, например, можно через [getStackTrace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()).

Comment: @StateItPrimitive спасибо за ответ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Реализуется через [получение StackTrace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()) текущего потока исполнения:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example().callerMethod();
    }

    public void callerMethod() {
        calledMethod();
    }

    public void calledMethod() {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        // 0 - это сам метод getStackTrace();
        // 1 - это вызываемый метод (calledMethod);
        // 2 - это вызывающий (родительский) метод (callerMethod).
        StackTraceElement stackTraceElement = stackTrace[2];
        System.out.println(stackTraceElement.getMethodName()); // callerMethod
    }
}
```